# React | http-proxy-middleware package not working

Tags: reactjs, http-proxy-middleware

[image]My application having multiple request to different API URL's request, when a particular component renders.
I am facing the CORS issue since I am using multiple URLs' , so in order to avoid i haved installed  http-proxy-middleware package.
In setupProxy.js, I used below code. which is not working
Note: I having same endpoints with different api urls's in my project. How deal with this cases

app.use(proxy("/rest/V1/orders",{target:"https://example.com/",changeOrigin:true}));
app.use(proxy("/rest/V1/orders",{target:"https://example.net/",changeOrigin:true}));
app.use(proxy("/rest/V1/orders",{target:"https://example.org/",changeOrigin:true}));

Comment: It's tricky to rewrite the URL properly when proxying - are you able to see details of the request that arrives at example.com etc.? What is the exact error? Debugging with an http client like postman always helps btw (to simulate the browser's outgoing request).

Comment: I am getting error intermittently, some times loading without any issue, PFB error

 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/xxxxx' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https:/xxx Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)


Attached screenshot

Comment: On the screenshot it looks like you're not sending the request to your own proxy (on localhost), but directly to the target instead?

Comment: Hi  i am running app from localhost  it is fetching different server, so I used http-proxy..

Comment: Right, but the request seems to be going from localhost *to* `cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` in the screenshot.

Comment: Exactly facing the same issue , i am sending request from localhost to dev or qa spring boot services . As @timotgl you said i am appending the URI `cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` + environment name + spring boot service name . eg:```https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://a1.sky.ie/sky-auth/portalloginuser``` . But my setupProxy app.use is not modifying to the target one. It got failed with my request url http://localhost:9009/sky-auth/portalloginuser 404 not found . can you please help me how to solve or any suggestion

Comment: @TBharathiraj how did you solve it. Can you make some sample post

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Download as ZIP file and check setupProxy.js in the SRC folder.
https://github.com/lyhd/reactjs/tree/fix-cors